# Flutter how to chose between two strings

Tags: flutter, dart

How to give predetermine string value.

Something like this.

```
class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final String type;
  const Button({
    this.type = 'raised' | 'text',
  });

}
```

That give me the error.

`In constant expressions, operands of this operator must be of type 'bool' or 'int'.`

How to give the parameter options to only be those predetermine string values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495815/dart-flutter-union-string-types

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart Flutter Union String types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495815/dart-flutter-union-string-types)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create a button with a stateless widget? If you need to know the state of that button, you should create a stateful widget.
I think you can refer to this navigation bar stateful example. (please ignore the title of the post) [How to create a button navigation bar with a stateless widget in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730813/how-to-create-a-button-navigation-bar-with-a-stateless-widget-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Define an enum:

```
enum MyButtonType {
  raised,
  text
}


class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyButtonType type;
  Button(this.type) {
     if (this.type==MyButtonType.raised) print("Raised Button");
  }
}
```